# Django ASGI New Relic getting a CORS Error Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, cors, newrelic

I am running a Django Application using Django channels and a daphne server (ASGI) instead of the typical gunicorn (WSGI) server. So I had to modify my application to this:

```
# asgi.py
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application
from asgiref.wsgi import WsgiToAsgi
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from newrelic import agent

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "server.settings")
django.setup()

application = agent.WSGIApplicationWrapper(get_wsgi_application())

application = WsgiToAsgi(application)
```

To my surprise this actually works. When I access my django api from a browser or postman it works properly and the data shows up in New Relic. However, I also have a client-side Angular web app which makes REST API calls to the django server and I am getting CORS errors.

Please note that this is not a regular CORS issue as when I remove the new relic wrapper I am able to access my API properly from Angular.

Failed to load `https://my-app.herokuapp.com/api/`: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `https://frontend.com` is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Change your asgi.py file something like this

```
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import newrelic.agent #import newrelic agent

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "server.settings")
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()
from django.conf import settings
newrelic_config_file = settings.BASE_DIR + "/newrelic.ini" #location of your newrelic.ini file
newrelic.agent.initialize(newrelic_config_file) #initialise agent
application = newrelic.agent.ASGIApplicationWrapper(django_asgi_app)
```